# Reduce the key value of dictionary by one

Tags: python, dictionary

Having a dictionary as below:

```
a_dict = {1: 'blue', 2: 'apple', 3: 'dog'}
```

need to reduce the key value by one and drop the blue value.

output:
a_dict = {1: 'apple', 2: 'dog'}

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is a bit strange (what is the real underlying goal?)

One option, assuming you want to keep the same order, and shift the values **after** blue to one key before:

```
l = list(a_dict.values())
l.remove('blue')

d = dict(zip(a_dict, l))
```

Output: `{1: 'apple', 2: 'dog'}`

*NB. In case of multiple 'blue', this would only remove the first one. To remove all:*

```
d = dict(zip(a_dict, [v for v in a_dict.values() if v != 'blue']))
```

##### dropping the first value

If you already know that the value to drop if the first one:

```
out = dict(zip(a_dict, list(a_dict.values())[1:]))
```

Or, more efficient:

```
i = iter(a_dict.values())
next(i) # consume first value
out = dict(zip(a_dict, i))
```

Comment: i mapped a list of elements into a dictionary.after some process i need to drop the first key-value pair and need to reindex the dictionary.

Comment: If you know the is the first one to drop: `dict(zip(a_dict, list(a_dict.values())[1:]))`

Comment: Another "efficient" but one-line option is to apply [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice): `dict(zip(a_dict, islice(a_dict.values(), 1, None)))`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, with `:=` operator:

```py
a_dict = {1: "blue", 2: "apple", 3: "dog"}

i = 0
a_dict = {i: v for v in a_dict.values() if v != "blue" and (i := i + 1)}
print(a_dict)
```

Prints:

```py
{1: 'apple', 2: 'dog'}
```